# Ebay .net Api - Get buyer's reviews

Tags: ebay-api

Does anyone knows how i can get buyer's reviews from a Product in a .Net Project from eBay API (soap , rest..).
Is there a way to do it with .net API?
Or must i build some custom crawler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "FindReviewsAndGuides".  You can search by product, by user, or by both:

http://apidocs.ebay.com/Shopping/CallRef/FindReviewsAndGuides.html

You can call the SOAP API with .NET.  There is a quick-start guide here:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/HowTo/FirstCall/MakingCallCSharp.html